# Resolve instance using named registration does not throw Exception

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, prism, unity-container

I thought I know a lot about Unity, but the following scenario I did not except. I´m using  Unity Container to register my views for Prism as objects with a named registration like so:

```
_unityContainer.RegisterType<object, MyDummyView>("MyDummyViewName");
```

and I request instance of the view by calling

```
object view = _unityContainer.Resolve<object>("MyDummyViewName");
```

So far so good. Now I found a bug in my system, cause I used the wrong name to resolve an instance of a view and I expected an exception to be thrown by Unity.

```
object view = _unityContainer.Resolve<object>("MyWrongDummyViewName");
```

But Unity does not throw any exception (like `ResolutionFailedException` or `ActivationException`). It returns a new `object`, when I do the call above, without registering any view with the given (wrong) name.

Is this a correct behavior by Unity? I really expected to get an exception here. In the scope of Prism this is a problem, cause I won´t get any exceptions during navigation to a wrong target (view).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm with you that this is unexpected behavior. I think the problem origins from the fact that you are trying to resolve an instance of a concrete class (in your case `object`). Looks like Unity will always try to resolve that instance. As long as it can do that it will ignore named mappings.

I experimented with a base class (`ViewBase`) which the container will also resolve unless you declare it `abstract`. Doing that raises the expected exception.

If you introduce an interface or abstract base class that should solve your problem.

You should open a [bug ticket for Unity](http://unity.codeplex.com/workitem/list/basic).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The problem is that [Prism Basic Region Navigation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg430861(v=pandp.40).aspx#sec8) needs my views to be registered as object. Otherwise can the Navigation infrastructure not resolve the views

Comment: This is by design behavior - Unity will attempt to resolve unregistered concrete classes. Since there was no registration for (object, "WhateverName") it new'ed up an instance of object. It isn't optimal, but it's not surprising.

Comment: @ChrisTavares The fact that Unity is trying to resolve concrete classes is known (and documented I believe). But that it ignores an explicitely specified name for the mapping ... This is different from Unity's behavior when asked for an interface and at least for me that *is* surprising.

Comment: @ChrisTavares do you know a way to configure or extend Unity, so that it throws an exception instead of creating an object